# Is it idiomatically correct to say "Her voice sounded lewd"?

Tags: word-request

I googled for this sentence, but I surprisingly found very few results. Is this sentence idiomatically wrong?

Also, is there an adjective that is related to both "thickness, oiliness" and *vulgarity* or *sexuality*, something similar to "Her oily smile" but only related to *lewdness*?

The context where I want to use this is the following:

> The interior was all red, and the women were all heavily made-up. Their voices were lewd.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that *idiomatically* speaking, no, this is not a viable phrase.  I've never come across this.  On the same token it is *mechanically* correct because it's an adjective.  You should therefore feel free to go ahead and use it and join the small ranks of other people that you found using it, too.

With regard to your second query, I think the word you're looking for is "husky":

> The interior was all red, and the women were all heavily made-up.
>   Their voices were *husky*.

Comment: I don't think that _husky_ is the right word here. Husky voices ain't necessarily sexy, but they are rough, robust, & sometimes grating. Lauren Bacall had a husky voice, but it wasn't lewd.

Comment: I chose "husky" because of how often it appears in both the _circumstances_ and _genre_ the question makes reference to.

Comment: Yes, it's a cliche. That's why Soulz should **not** use it. His ideas about what to say and how to say it don't seem to welcome cliched remarks. That's why I answer his questions. They're interesting. Cliches aren't.

Comment: Yet clichés are important to be aware of when learning a second language.  Artistically they may not be interesting, but communicatively, they can be quite useful for the L2 learner/writer.

Comment: True enough, but Soulz is a writer, so I treat him as a writer rather than as a typical EFL student.

Comment: I like this answer; I think more of lewd _words_ than lewd _voices_. When using an adjective to modify _voices_, I'd want a word that talks more about the quality of the voices themselves, as opposed to whatever choice words might be uttered. If the O.P. doesn't like _husky_ for some reason, then _seductive_ could be considered.

Comment: @J.R.: I like "seductive", but it ain't necessarily "lewd". I think that [RuPaul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RuPaul) is lewd in just about every way. And huskies go "Ruff! Ruff!" Wasn't that Dennis the Menace's dog's name?

Comment: @Bill: Precisely why I often clamor for more context. A few more sentences about this red room full of women, and I might say, "Yes! _Seductive_ is exactly the word you want," or I might say, "Oh, no, I was off; these women are far too lewd to be labeled as _seductive_." As it stands now, though, there are a whole range of potential candidates. But I like _husky_, too, particularly in the sense [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/husky_5) defines it.

Comment: @J.R.: Describes Lauren Bacall's and Greta Garbo's voices: rough & attractive but not lewd. But you're right about the context being insufficient: "In the [red] room with black curtains near the station. // Black-roof country, no gold pavements, tired starlings. // Silver horses run down moonbeams in your dark eyes. // Dawn-light smiles on you leaving, my contentment. // I'll wait in this place where the sun never shines; // Wait in this place where the shadows run from themselves."

Comment: @Bill: I agree that _husky_ and _seductive_ aren't the same as _lewd_. Here is my problem, though: I'm unsure of how "lewd" the O.P. really wants to be. Particularly in an English Learners forum, it's conceivable that one would propose _lewd_ when perhaps they were really desiring a word more along the lines of _risque_ or _suggestive_. That's why, until I get more clarification asserting otherwise, I'm not ready to throw out _husky_ yet.

Comment: @J.R.: No argument here. No context means no possibility of a definitive answer. But the bot says the discussion's too long now.

Comment: Here's an [alternative](http://www.mail.com/int/entertainment/celebrity/2005782-spanish-film-star-sara-montiel-dies-age-85.html#.1258-stage-set3-2) word: "Sara Montiel, a famed, **[sultry-voiced](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sultry)** Spanish actress who became the first to also achieve Hollywood stardom, died Monday."

Answer (score 1):

Google Ngram Viewer shows hits for "lewd voice" and "[lewd voices](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lewd%20voices&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)" from 1800 until today, so it certainly isn't unusual.

If you've read enough English literature, you'll find myriad phrases that make sense in context, are grammatical, are semantically acceptable (even if the metaphor is a stretch), and aren't necessarily idiomatic in the sense that they're commonplace expressions. There's nothing wrong with the English, but that doesn't mean that everyone reading it will like it, in which case they will say "It's not good" or "It's not proper" or "It's weird". I don't think it's weird at all. It conjures a clear image for me.

You can probably use *smarmy* or *unctuous* or *lubricious* for "oily" related to lewdness.

Answer (score 0):

*Lewd* can be used as adjective to describe (for example) photos, remarks, song parodies, laughters, or jokes. If I would read "Their voices were lewd." I would understand that as "Their voices were obscene." probably said in a figurative way.

Comment: "Obscene" is one synonym, but so are "lascivious" and "salacious".

Answer (score 0):

It's not an idiom, but it is certainly a valid usage.

The phrase the "interior was all red, and the women were all heavily made-up" focuses the reader on the women's faces. "Their voices were lewd" further focuses on the source of their voices -- their mouths. "Lewd" has several connotations. The author is leading the reader but still letting them form their own conception of what a lewd voice might be, and what it implies of the women. I think it's a fantastic usage.

Answer (score 0):

Gramatically speaking, it sounds correct, we are not just assuming that is correct, but it can also be understood just by pronouncing it either from a sentence or a statement.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how pronunciation is involved. Could you [edit] your post to explain that a bit?